# Pros/Cons of Saving the State of a Paused VirtualBox Appliance?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

Are there any differences i.e. advantages/disadvantages to saving the machine state of a VirtualBox appliance while it is paused?

I used to save the machine state of appliances without them being paused (Close -> Save the Machine State), but have just found out that if I do this after pausing the appliance that it seems to have the same effect.  In fact, when I start the appliance again, it is automatically unpaused, which is interesting.

Does anyone know if pausing an appliance affects saving the machine state in any way?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually that's some of the perks of working with Virtual Machines, not to mention the security and consistence you get if you work with them. Saving the state machine and other ways does not affect the performance of them, you even can do things like:

- You can move the copy to another installation and resume your
  execution.
- Do snapshots of the Virtual Machines. Which is something like a "photo" of that moment of the Virtual Machine.
- Cloning it to run another copy on the host.
- Live migration and this does not affect the processes of the user.

If you want to learn more, I recommend you this book: http://iips.icci.edu.iq/images/exam/Abraham-Silberschatz-Operating-System-Concepts---9th2012.12.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link to the great book.  My question was more aimed at the effect of pausing a VirtualBox appliance before saving its state.  You can save the appliance state while it is unpaused as well... I was just curious if the pausing did anything special.